# HTML tags not work in the struts2 tags

Tags: html, struts2, ckeditor

I am using CK-EDITOR to get input from the user and save the input in the database.
When I am showing this trough struts2 tag the HTML tag inserted through CK-EDITOR not working.

It show in the jsp page like :

```
<p> <strong>Because of your browser security settings, the editor is not able to access your clipboard data directly. You are required to paste it again in this window</strong></p>
```

Comment: I got the way to do this
By adding the tag attribute   **escape="false"**

     <s:property value="comment" escape="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use property `escape="false"` to fix it:

```
<s:property escape="false" value="matchBean.links" />
```

It will display the HTML tag.